# Can't select text in terminal after upgrading to VIM 8 on Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: debian, vim

I recently upgraded to Debian 9 Stretch. It includes VIM 8.

Previously, I could select text with the mouse and copy and paste it using the terminal application. Now this initiates "visual" mode which I have read [the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html) for.

Using the mouse, it selects text using VIM instead of the terminal, and I cannot copy it.

I can't see any way of disengaging this, except recompiling with visual mode disabled.

There must be a way, right?

Comment: `:h defaults.vim` and `:h 'mouse'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in stretch, VIM 8 uses a new defaults.vim file in `/usr/share/vim/vim80/`

in this file i commented out the `set mouse=a` and it had the desired result. i don't run vim heavily customised, so i am happy with this.

Comment: This will be overwritten when vim gets updated, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

In */etc/vim/vimrc* strarting from line #12 is reported how to solve your problem (globally).

Enabling the line containing:

> let g:skip_defaults_vim = 1

you can disable vim defaults and, after that, set what you want.

Otherwise you can do that in a local ~/.vimrc